# C# Dynamic Casting with GetType()

Tags: c#, .net, types, casting, overloading

I've read many posts trying to accomplish similar tasks but cannot find a proper solution to my problem.

I'm trying to dynamically cast an object at runtime. (I know a lot of you are going to say it can't be done, and I'm not actually sure if it can...) My problem is that I have a dynamically created `TreeView` in a `Windows Forms Application` to display an `Org Chart`.

The data in the `TreeView` pulls from 3 tables: `Departments`, `Jobs`, `Employees`.

Importing the `Tables` as a `Local DataSource` gives me all 3 Tables as `DataSet` Objects, and templates for `DataRow` objects type casted to the table it comes from (including all columns as properties). (Similar to linq - except for Oracle DB)

I create `TreeNode` objects, use a description field from my `DataRow` as the `TreeNode.Text` Property and then attach the `DataRow` itself as the `TreeNode.Tag` property. This way, I can access the data from directly within the `TreeNode` simply by casting:

```cs
dsMyDataSource.DepartmentRow = 
    (dsMyDataSource.DepartmentRow)treeview1.SelectedNode.Tag;
```

I have a method that runs whenever the User selects a `Node` on `treeview1` that populates a `Details` window with some of the underlying objects data. As of right now, I have a single method with a switch statement as such:

```cs
private doSomething()
{
    switch(treeview1.SelectedNode.Tag.GetType().Name)
    {
        case "dsMyDataSource.DepartmentRow":
            dsMyDataSource.DepartmentRow department = 
                (dsMyDataSource.DepartmentRow)treeview1.SelectedNode.Tag;
            lblDetailsTitle = department.Title;
            break;
        case "dsMyDataSource.JobRow":
            //etc...
    }
}
```

What I want to do, is to have overloaded methods for each type and get rid of my switch statements. Like so:

```cs
this.doSomething(treeview1.SelectedNode.Tag);
```

Problem is, this returns a base object (thus the cast). But I don't know at compile time what type of TreeNode the User will select. Thus I want to be able to do something like:

```cs
this.doSomething((treeview1.SelectedNode.Tag.GetType())treeview1.SelectedNode.Tag);

private void doSomething(dsMyDataSource.DepartmentRow department)
{
    lblDetailsTitle = department.Title;
    // etc...
}

private void doSomething(dsMyDataSource.JobRow job) {..}

private void doSomething(dsMyDataSource.EmployeeRow employee) {..}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You could solve this with class inheritance without any casting. Define a base type that your Tag'd objects descend from that includes a virtual method for the `doSomething` code to act on, and provide concrete implementations in each concrete type.

Comment: Sounds like a task that's been redone a million times since computers were invented and yet you find a new problem... which usually means you're doing it wrong. Implement an interface in all your objects of interest, no need of casting other than to the interface itself

Answer (score 1):

You might find things cleaner if you use some meaningful objects rather than working directly off DataRows.  In addition this will let you add a base class, which will make your casting problems go away.

So for example you could have

```
abstract class Selectable
{
    public string Type { get; private set; }

    public Selectable(string type) { Type = type; }

    abstract void doSomething();
}
```

and then a type for each thing you want to select

```
class Department : Selectable{...}, class Job : Selectable{...}
```

To get the base types you will need one switch in a factory object.

```
public static class SelectableFactory
{
    public static Selectable GetFromDataRow(DataRow dr)
    {
        Selectable res = null;
        switch (dr.Type)
        {
            case "Department":
                res = new Department(dr);
                // etc ...
            }
    }
}
```

But you now have a collection of Selectables that can use polymorphism to do the action.

In addition to making your life easier it will make your code much easier to parse for anyone else that has to work on it in the future.  It's also extensible, so when you need to add a DoSomethingElse method it's much easier to add for everything - or when you need a new type of datatable you don't disturb your UI code.